# Cross-field-validation with composition api in custom input fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

**Versions**

Hello,

I am using [vee-validate 4](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/composition-helpers) with vuejs 3 and [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to create a "SignUp"-form. Now as I need to style every input field (and some of them are really complex), I am trying to add the validation logic to the specific fields.

This is the form itself:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Form @submit="onSubmit">
      <PasswordField name="password" />
      <PasswordField name="confirmpassword" confirm_field/>
      <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Form } from "vee-validate";
import PasswordField from "./components/PasswordField.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    PasswordField,
    Form,
  },
  setup() {
    function onSubmit(values) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }

    return {
      onSubmit,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And this is the custom field

```
<template>
    <input :id="name"
           :class="{'form-input': true, 'form-error': errors[0]}"
           :name="name"
           :value="inputValue"
           type="password"
           @change="onChange"
           @input="onInput($event)"
    />
    <span v-if="show_error">{{ errorMessage }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import {useField} from 'vee-validate';
import * as yup from 'yup';

export default {
    name: 'PasswordField',
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        show_error: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            default: "",
        },
        confirm_field: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    setup (props) {

        let rules = yup.string ().required ().min (5);

        if (props.confirm_field) {
            rules = yup.string ()
            .required ().min (5)
            .oneOf ([yup.ref ("password")])
        }

        const {
            value: inputValue,
            errors,
            errorMessage,
            handleBlur,
            handleChange,
            handleInput
        } = useField (props.name, rules, {initialValue: props.inputValue});

        return {
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            errors,
            errorMessage,
            inputValue,
            handleInput
        };
    },
    watch: {
        /* Syncs the value if it was updated from outside */
        modelValue (val) {
            this.inputValue = val;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onInput (event) {
            this.handleInput (event);
            this.$emit ('update:modelValue', event.target.value);
        },
        onChange (event) {
            this.handleChange (event);
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

The validation of the confirmpassword-field fails with:

> this must be one of the following values: Ref(password)

So it seems the reference to the password-input is not working correctly.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Hi Dan, I am aware of that, but I'd like to add fields that come with their own validation-logic as I don't want to repeat the rules for an email-field over and over again.

Comment: I have to evaluate this - I'm kinda new to yup and I am using it with dee-validate and it's `<Form>`. I have to figure out whether this is building up a yup-schema "under the hood" or not. As you can see I am using yup-rules and of course I could pass the other field's value as a prop and check, whether this is, but I thought I could somehow grab the field without passing the value directly.